# 100% width container with 8 same size inputs

Tags: html, css

I have a 100% width container that I would like to fill with 8 inputs of the same size. 100 / 8 = 12.5

The html:

```
<div id="container">
<input class="form" />
<input class="form" />
....
</div>
```

My css:

```
#container{
  width: 100%;
  background-color:red;
  margin:0;
}

.form{
  width:12.5%;
  margin:0;
}
```

As you can see in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7z7e63cb/

The last input is displayed in another line. **Why? and how can I fix it?**  Thanks

Comment: Are you using any framework??

Comment: The line break after each input element takes up a white space character, of which you have a total of 7, and this causes the over all line length to be greater than 100%.

Comment: Have a look at [this updated jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7z7e63cb/14/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion, the best way to do this in 2016 is to use Flexbox: see [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7z7e63cb/10/).

The main trick is done with the following lines:

```
#container{
  ...
  display: flex; /* turns the Flexbox magic on! */
}

.form{
  flex: 1; /* makes the elements equal width, no extra calculation needed */
  min-width: 0; /* allows them to shrink below their default width */
  ...
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#container {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex; /* turns the Flexbox magic on! */
}
.form {
  flex: 1; /* makes the elements equal width, no extra calculation needed */
  min-width: 0; /* allows them to shrink below their default width */
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <input class="form" />
  <input class="form" />
  <input class="form" />
  <input class="form" />
  <input class="form" />
  <input class="form" />
  <input class="form" />
  <input class="form" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to do two things

1. Remove white-space from HTML
2. Use `box-sizing: border-box` on inputs because of default border and padding

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#container {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0;
}
.form {
  width: 12.5%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <input class="form" /><!--
  --><input class="form" /><!--
  --><input class="form" /><!--
  --><input class="form" /><!--
  --><input class="form" /><!--
  --><input class="form" /><!--
  --><input class="form" /><!--
  --><input class="form" />
</div>
```

Comment: Rather than commenting out the line-break/white-space you could, alternatively, set `font-size: 0;` for the `#container` and `font-size: 1rem;` for the `<input>` elements.

Comment: @DavidThomas: Yep, this seems to be more elegant and flexible solution

Comment: -`box-sizing` alone wouldn't help in this case, since it doesn't take into account the inter-word whitespaces.- _read these numbers as alternatives, not consecutive steps, sorry._ `font-size: 0;` is one of the best CSS options to remove spaces without markup changes, but it still may cause some artifacts in some browsers (e.g. https://codepen.io/stowball/details/LsICH). Removing spaces looks more reliable, but I prefer the Flexbox solution to them all.

Comment: It is still not working somehow?: https://jsfiddle.net/7z7e63cb/13/ the updated code

Comment: @John Smith Like i said you also need to remove white-space from html https://jsfiddle.net/7z7e63cb/16/ or as other suggested you can use font-size https://jsfiddle.net/7z7e63cb/17/

Answer (score 0):

Because of **white spaces**, it is taking *few length of the div*, and hence your ***'forms'*** does not fit in a line.
You can either
*. Reduce your form width to `11.5%` for each. or,
*. Remove the white spaces.

Answer (score 0):

There are more factors involved in the content width than just the width of the input field.

I've added `border:0;` to the `.form` class, and removed the line break(s) between the inputs in your html.

This will then result in the 100% width you're looking for, as per the updated fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/ghcuhwpo/